# successful mysql connection but no database selected?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Using mysqli for the first time and struggling with the prepared statement. 
Is this a *database* problem, or a *table* problem?

This is using the CodeIgniter framework with autoconfig...
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

1. I'm using a database.php auto configuration file
2. my connection is made by `$con = mysqli_connect() or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));` and appears to be successful.
3. my prepared statement is `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO table(documentID) VALUES (?)");`
4. Then when I check the prepared statement I get an error `1046 No database selected`But my code just told the database selection/connection is fine.

Over view in my model below:

```
$con = mysqli_connect() or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

if (!$con) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "<b>";
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($con) . PHP_EOL;

//Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! 

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO table(documentID) VALUES (?)");
if (!$stmt) {
        echo "Problem <b>";
        $error = $con->errno . ' ' . $con->error;
            echo $error; // 1046 No database selected
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: How can the connection be successful without host, user or password? This is a *connection* problem.

Comment: `$con = mysqli_connect()` if that's your real code, pretty obvious here. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: but that's all provided in my autoconfiguration file....?!?!   .../application/config/database.php    Sorry I should have mentioned I'm using the CodeIgniter framework

Comment: it doesn't quite work that way

Comment: So what's the point then of the CodeIgniter autoconfig file?  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: Have you [read this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html) or [this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html?highlight=database%20connection)?

Comment: because, CI is a different animal altogether and doesn't use the same syntax. Edit: *Ain't that right Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard, yes I have.    OK, well I'll scrap the autoconfig approach and just write it explicitly in my code. There's something there I'm not understanding and I'll have to look at it later.

Comment: Configuration of any type still requires that you specify certain items, such as the host, user, password, database, etc.

Comment: another thing, CI uses a different method as a prepared statement https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to create separate database configurations if you only need to use a different database on the same connection. You can switch to a different database when you need to, like this:

```
$this->db->db_select($database2_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that there are several layers to consider when making a database connection. First you need to connect to the server, then you connect to your database of choice. Once that's done then you can run your query.

Take a look at the PHP manual entry for mysqli_connect()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

It's not too surprising that there would be no mysqli errors after the mysqli_connect method is contructed because you never actually asked it to do anything.

Comment: ... you never actually asked it to do anything....     I think that is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

For easier reading for the next person who may run into this.... there's a couple of fragments that answered my question.

- Fred-ii pointed out that "CI uses a different method as a prepared statement"
  Looking back, I don't know how I lost track of that. All of a suddent I was struggling mysqli statements outside of the CodeIgniter framework, and barking up the wrong tree.
- OffTheBricks pointed out that "It's not too surprising that there would be no mysqli errors after the mysqli_connect method is contructed because you never actually asked it to do anything."

Obviously, the assumption that my autoconfig was right, and that the error checking saying that all is well with my database connection, was simply because I was mixing two different techniques: CodeIgniter autoconfig file, and the standard mysqli.

Thanks for the help... feel like a bit of an idiot now.